# Statistics in the Monte Carlo experiment

Tags: anylogic

I have the following model.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGbft.jpg)

I need to use the Monte Carlo experiment and get statistics. An example should be.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl5jO.jpg)

But when running, nothing is displayed on the graph. How do I link this stats to a model?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example models that include optimization. In them, focus on the code in the Java fields of the experiment as below:
[image]

The "root" keyword is the important bit as it lets you access anything from Main after a simulation run. You copy what you need after each run into your optimization experiment and then do with it whatever you want.